# Azure DevOps export variable as sequence or mapping

Tags: azure-devops

I need to run the same actions described in `template.yml` agains list of objects I'm getting from some API

That list of objects is always new and I can't predefine it

I export list from Python script: `print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable=validRepos]{validRepos}')`

Here's how it looks in pipeline's task:
[image]

I'm trying to use it in pipeline:

```
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    param: $(validRepos)
```

..but getting the following error:
[image]

Is it possible to export variable as sequence or mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have used this similar statement in the template.yml `- ${{ each step in parameters.buildSteps }}:`.

The error occurred is because the template expression `${{}}` is parsed at compile time. But the value of variable `$(validRepos)` is produced at run time. When the agent pipeline parsed the template, the jobs has not be executed and the value of variable `$(validRepos)` is not generated yet. For this reason the pipeline failed with above error. Please check the document [understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax).

The workaround is use commands (ie. powershell task) to execute your task. And move the iteration operation inside the commands task. For below simple example of powershell task.

```
parameters:
  buildSteps: []

steps:
- powershell: |
    foreach($step in ${{parameters.buildSteps}}){
      write-host $step
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work. But my main goal is to run dedicated JOB for each entity in {validRepos} list, is it possible?

Comment: It is not possible. You have to either change your JOB into powershell commands, or manually set the validRepos' value to template's parameter.(ie. `parameters:
    param: ["repo1","epo1"]`). You can also submit a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/353097/queuing-a-devops-build-via-rest-api-using-triggere.html) (Click suggest a feature and choose Azure Devops) for supporting dynamic template parameters